# read in csv files from a folder and create html files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, operating-system, glob

I'm new to python and hoping for some help to read in csv files from a folder and converting each file to a html folder...this is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
  
 
path = "htmlplots"
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for file in csv_files:
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # print the filename
    print('File Name:', file.split("\\")[-1])
    # print the content
    display(df)
```

Ideally I then need to create html files from the resulting csv files that have a 'next' and 'previous' link from one to two, two to three (next) and three to two, two to one (previous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = ""

csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
for i, file in enumerate(csv_files):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header = None)
    name = file.split('.')[-1]
    
    
    if i>0:
        prev = csv_files[i-1]
        df.loc['prev',:]=f'http://{prev}'
    else:
        df.loc['prev',:]=''
    if i!=len(csv_files)-1:
        next = csv_files[i+1]
        df.loc['next',:]=f'http://{next}'
    else:
        df.loc['next',:]=''
    df.to_html(f"{file}.html", render_links = True)
```

Input csv file:

[image]

Output html:

[image]

Comment: that results in creating html code in .csv files...

Comment: See the edited answer now.

Comment: thanks this has got me closer to solving what i need, except i need a html file for each .csv file, ill try and build on your skeleton to do that thanks :)

Comment: It is a for loop, so for every csv file there will be an html output.

Comment: Look at the answer again.